# postStart lifecycle hook not availavle for kubectl exec

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following postStart lifecycle hook configured.

```
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /bin/sh
                  - -c
                  - >
                  export FOO="foo";
```

However, when I `kubectl exec -it my-pod -- sh -c 'echo $FOO'` doesn't return anything.

Likewise, I can see from `kubectl exec -it my-pod -- env` that the variable is not set.

Comment: Setting environment variables only happen in the process they run in. See the docs on assigning env vars to containers https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

Comment: This isn't really specific to Kubernetes -- this is just how environment variables work in Unix-like operating systems. A process can only effect its own environment and those of its children. A child command cannot set environment variables in its parent.

Comment: okay, but why does it work after I exec in? if I `kubectl exec -it my-pod -- sh` and then run   `echo $FOO` it works? Is it that `postStart` happens after `kubectl exec -it` into the shell?

Comment: It "works" because you set the env in your spec. If you "export anotherfoo=nextfoo" in current shell; exit and re-exec; or exec simultaneously; you will **not** see "anotherfoo".

Answer (score 0):

You Larsks & jordanm mentioned it's on process level **poststart, prestop** hook or **init container** not share the environment variables.

You have to write values to the file and with a shared path, you can share that file.

it's useless but you can do something like this, you can also set direct variables, if you have you can use shared file system:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: ubuntu
        command: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'source /var/tmp/hello.txt && sleep infinity']
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'echo export FOO="foo" > /var/tmp/hello.txt']
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```